# getting "the given header is not found" while connecting to cosmos db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

[image]

trying to insert data into cosmo db but while trying to verify in connection string getting error as shown in figure,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After my test,I reproduce your issue when I try to configure the AccountName to be my cosmos db table api.

[image]

Based on this [official statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-import#data-migration-tool), The UI based Data Migration tool (dtui.exe) is not currently supported for Table API accounts.

[image]

You could try to use `command-line Azure Cosmos DB Data Migration tool (dt.exe)`.

If I connected to Cosmos DB SQL API, everything was fine.

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You should also pay attention to the domain in you "AccountEndpoint" string. Azure portal gives "AccountEndpoint" in "Connection String" section of "Azure Cosmos DB account" service and it looks like https://$YOUR_ACCOUNTNAME.table.cosmos.azure.com:443/. If you try to work with this endpoint in dt.exe - you'll get the described error. In case if you replace "table.cosmos.azure.com:443/" with "documents.azure.com:443/" - you'll pass the verifying successfully. This trick with domains and non-informative error have wasted 1 hour of my only life.

Comment: Unfortunately even though your trick with the host name gets round verification for me it then proceeds to export to JSON a empty JSON file.  Have you managed to export to JSON successfully from table API using the UI tool?

Comment: As I found in my notes, I have used dt v.1.8.3 for this stuff:
`./dt.exe /s:DocumentDB /s.ConnectionString:"AccountEndpoint=https://tablename.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=somekey==;Database=db_name" /s.Collection:"collection_name" /t:JsonFile /t.File:"1.json" /ErrorDetails:All`